# How to configure mutliple transaction managers with Spring + Teradata

Tags: java, spring, teradata, spring-transactions

We have an requirement wherein we need to have multiple datasources for different teradata database users. Now for these different datasources how we can configure multiple transaction manager.

We have different database users as per their privileges and priorities given at DB level. Suggest how we effectively we can configure transaction management with spring.

Comment: what have your tried ?

Comment: We have used DataSourceTransactionManager for spring jdbc templates and JPAtransactionmanager for hibernate entitymanager configuration. We have one datasource attached with JPA entitymanager and one datasource attched with spring JDBCTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You can define several bean of type transactionManager like this:

```
<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager2"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager3"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Then in spring in the @Transactional annotation you can use one of the defined transaction manager like this:

```
@Transactional(value = "hibernateTransactionManager", rollbackFor = { MyException.class })
```

Angelo